# How to create an array of different size as a private class variable?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that takes a polynomial function from the user, counts the number of terms it has, creates an array large enough to store all of the terms, and then stores the terms there. The problem is that I'm not quite sure how to add a private class variable (or more specifically, a string array) AFTER the program determines how the large the function is. I need this string array to be a private class variable because I want to be able to access its contents through other class methods to do things like, for example, cout each of the function terms.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Function.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Function func1;
    func1.coutFuncTerms();
    func1.coutFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Function.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H
#define FUNCTION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Function.h"
using namespace std;

class Function
{
    public:
        Function();
        ~Function();
        void removePlus(string*);
        void removeWhitespace(string*);
        void setFuncTerms();
        void splitTerms();
        void coutFuncTerms();
        void coutFunc();
        void coutTerms(string);
    protected:
    private:
        string func;
        int funcTerms;
};

#endif
```

Function.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Function.h"
using namespace std;

// Function Constructor
//
// Stores a function inputted by the user
// Adds a null character ('\0') to the end of a string
// Erases a redundant '+' sign at the beginning of a string if there's one there
// Erases any whitespace characters in a string
// Stores the number of terms in the function
Function::Function()
{
    getline(cin, func);
    setFuncTerms();
    //splitTerms();
}

Function::~Function()
{

}

// removePlus Function
//
// Erases a redundant '+' sign at the beginning of a string if there's one there
void Function::removePlus(string* func)
{
    if(func->at(0) == '+')
    {
        func->erase(0, 1);
    }
}

// removeWhitespace Function
//
// Erases any whitespace characters in a string
void Function::removeWhitespace(string* func)
{
    for(int x = 0; unsigned(x) < func->length() - 1; x++)
    {
        while(func->at(x) == ' ' || func->at(x) == '\t')
        {
            func->erase(x, 1);
        }
    }
}

// setFuncLength Function
//
// Finds the number of terms in a Function object's 'func' variable
// Assigns this number to the object's 'funcLength' variable
void Function::setFuncTerms()
{
    funcTerms = 0;
    for(int funcTerm = 0; unsigned(funcTerm) < func.length(); funcTerm += 1)
    {
        bool isAPotentialTerm = false;
        bool isATrueTerm = false;
        if(func.at(funcTerm) == '+' || func.at(funcTerm) == '-')
        {
            isAPotentialTerm = true;
        }
        if(isAPotentialTerm == true)
        {
            for(int newFuncTerm = funcTerm + 1; unsigned(newFuncTerm) < func.length(); newFuncTerm += 1)
            {
                if(func.at(newFuncTerm) == '+' || func.at(newFuncTerm) == '-')
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(func.at(newFuncTerm) != ' ' && func.at(newFuncTerm) != '\t')
                {
                    isATrueTerm = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isATrueTerm)
        {
            funcTerms++;
        }
    }
}

// splitTerms Function
//
// Calls the splitTerm function for each term in 'func' according to the function array 'funcArray'
void Function::splitTerms()
{
    string funcArray[funcTerms];
    int tempFuncLength = 0;
    for(int funcTerm = 0; unsigned(funcTerm) < func.length(); funcTerm += 1)
    {
        bool isAPotentialTerm = false;
        bool isATrueTerm = false;
        if(func.at(funcTerm) == '+' || func.at(funcTerm) == '-')
        {
            isAPotentialTerm = true;
        }
        if(isAPotentialTerm == true)
        {
            for(int newFuncTerm = funcTerm + 1; unsigned(newFuncTerm) < func.length(); newFuncTerm += 1)
            {
                if(func.at(newFuncTerm) == '+' || func.at(newFuncTerm) == '-')
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(func.at(newFuncTerm) != ' ' && func.at(newFuncTerm) != '\t')
                {
                    isATrueTerm = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isATrueTerm)
        {
            string temp;
            for(; unsigned(funcTerm) < func.length() && func.at(funcTerm) != '+' && func.at(funcTerm) != '-'; funcTerm += 1)
            {
                funcArray[tempFuncLength].append(1, func.at(funcTerm));
            }
            tempFuncLength++;
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < funcTerms; x++)
    {
        cout << "Term " << x + 1 << " is: " << funcArray[x] << endl;
    }
}

void Function::coutFuncTerms()
{
    cout << "Terms: " << funcTerms << endl;
}

void Function::coutFunc()
{
    cout << "Function: " << func << endl;
}

void Function::coutTerms(string funcArrayTerm)
{
    /*for(int x = 0; x < funcLength; x++)
    {
        cout << "Term " << x << " is: " << funcArray[x] << endl;
    }*/
    //cout << funcArray[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `std::vector`.

Comment: The code is indeed horrible, but we can easily improve it. I don't understand what you want to do. Can you provide a an usage example of the class `Function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you change your design.

A *function* is a container of *terms*.  So let's define a *term*:

A term minimally has a *coefficient* and an exponent:

```
struct Fundamental_Term
{
  double coefficient;
  int    exponent;
};
```

If your function is only in terms of one variable, all you need is the `Fundamental_Term`.  Otherwise, you need to have the base variable name:

```
struct Term_With_Base
: public Fundamental_Term
{
  std::string variable_name;
};
```

*Note: if you can't use inheritance, copy the member variables of `Fundamental_Term` into `Term_With_Base`.*

Remember a *function* is a collection or container of terms.  Assuming a function with multiple bases, we can declare:

```
struct Function
{
  std::vector<Term_With_Base> terms;
};
```

**Evaluation of Terms**
To evaluate a function, f(x), all terms must be evaluated and their results summed.
This decomposes into two requirements:  1) Terms must have an evaluation method; 2) The function class must have an evaluation method that sums the terms.

So, we add an evaluation function to the base class:

```
struct Fundamental_Term
{
  double coefficient;
  int exponent;
  double evaluate(double value)
  {
    return coefficient * pow(value, exponent);
  }
};

struct Function
{
  std::vector<Term_With_Base> terms;
  double evauate(double value)
  {
    const unsigned int quantity = terms.size();
    double result = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
    {
      result = result + terms[i].evaluate(value);
    }
    return result;
   }
};
```

When creating a function from a string, a preference is to create a constructor of `Fundamental_Term` that takes a string parameter.  The term object should read its coefficient, variable name and exponent, not the Function container.

For more examples, search StackOverflow for "c++ parse term evaluation".

**Edit 1:  Inserting terms**
One method to insert terms, is to have a method in the term data structure that loads a term from a string:

```
bool
Fundamental_Term ::
load_from string(const std::string& input,
                 unsigned int &     start_position)
{
  bool term_is_valid = false;
  // Parse the string and load appropriate fields.
  // Set the start position to the first position after the valid term.
  // Set term_is_valid to true if the term has valid syntax.
  return term_is_valid;
}
```

The Function object would have a member to load terms from a string.

```
bool
Function ::
load_terms_from_string(const std::string& input)
{
  Term_With_Base term;
  unsigned int   position_in_string = 0;
  bool           term_is_valid = true;
  while (term_is_valid && (position_in_string < input.size()))
  {
    term_is_valid = term.load_from_string(input, position_in_string);
    if (term_is_valid)
    {
      terms.push_back(term);
    }
  }
}
```

The `std::vector` used to contain the terms will expand as necessary with each additional term that is parsed.  The loop will terminate when the string is parsed or there is an invalid term.